# Buffredreader read next line

Tags: java, bufferedreader

how would i go about reading the next line using a buffered reader.

I am currently reader each line, but would like to read the next line whilst reading the current line.

this is my code

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily, but what you can do is to read the current line and remember the previous line

```
for(String prev = null, line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; prev = line) {
      // you have prev and line
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Will both `line` and `prev` variable be always equal?

Comment: I would like to check some values in the next line to check some values in the next line. Your code works, but not suitable for what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Octopus The `prev` will be the previous line and `line` will be the current line.

Comment: @user3588388 If I rename name `prev` to `line` and `line` to `next` would that help? I assume you just don't how to apply it to your use case. Can you say why it wouldn't do what you want?

Comment: @PeterLawrey +1 Thanks, I get it now when i rethink about it :) I need to improve my logical thinking.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - I want to check for an specific object on the current line, if it returns a true, then check the next line for another object.

Comment: @user3588388 So this loop can do that.